# How to get a picture from the photo library with PhoneGap on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using the following code:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(successFunc, errorFunc,{
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
```

But the photolibrary is not shown. Instead, the camera is activated. I'm using Android 5.

Comment: What version of PhoneGap/Cordova? What version of the Camera plugin? I ran your code on Cordova Android 5.1.0 and Camera Plugin 2.1.0 and it worked fine on my Android 5.1 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine on all devices running android 5+  :

```
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onProfilePicURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 100,//
        //targetWidth : 512,
        //targetHeight : 512,
        allowEdit : true,
        destinationType : destinationType.DATA_URL,
        correctOrientation : true,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers.
This problem was solved by updating the platform